# Update image using javascript in amMap - Amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

There is a map with images, on clicking these images makes a list of selected items. On clicking the selected images in the map unselect the images and remove those items from the selected item list.

I'm trying to unselect the selected items from the list and update the image in the map.

I tried to do that with the **imageSeries**, which changes the href and imageURL but the change is not reflecting on the map.

```
imageSeries.dataItems.getIndex(index).dataContext.imageURL = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

and

```
imageSeries.dataItems.getIndex(index).href = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

- The images can be seen after clicking on the dense state i.e Uttar Pradesh
- On clicking the image create a list of selected items and change the image
- On clicking the changed image, unselects the selected item and update image

How to change the images on clicking the list items of the same id?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/fuhkt8xs/)